# data analysis using gps coordinates

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gps, data-analysis, analysis

I have this kind of data, which contain Timestamp, longitude,latitude and tripId,

can i probably find the waiting time in intersection from only this data or i need something else?
and which informations can i get from this kind of data?

> "timestamp","tripId","longitude","latitude"
> "2021-07-05 10:35:04","1866491","8.167035","53.160473"
> "2021-07-05 10:35:03","1866491","8.167023","53.160469"
> "2021-07-05 10:35:02","1866491","8.167007","53.160459"
> "2021-07-05 10:35:01","1866491","8.166987","53.160455"
> "2021-07-05 10:35:00","1866491","8.166956","53.160448"
> "2021-07-05 10:34:20","1866491","8.167286","53.15919"
> "2021-07-05 10:34:19","1866491","8.167328","53.15918"
> "2021-07-05 10:34:18","1866491","8.16735","53.159165"
> "2021-07-05 10:34:17","1866491","8.167371","53.159148"
> "2021-07-05 10:34:16","1866491","8.167388","53.159124"
> "2021-07-05 10:34:15","1866491","8.167399","53.159105"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:30","1862861","8.211288","53.150848"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:29","1862861","8.211264","53.150851"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:28","1862861","8.211269","53.150842"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:27","1862861","8.211273","53.150836"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:26","1862861","8.211279","53.150836"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:25","1862861","8.211259","53.150848"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:24","1862861","8.211263","53.15085"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:21","1862861","8.211455","53.150782"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:20","1862861","8.211453","53.150786"
> "2021-06-30 20:25:19","1862861","8.211449","53.150792"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this question:

> which informations can i get from this kind of data

You have a `timestamp`, a `tripId` and a coordinate (`longitude` and `latitude`).

Therefore, **you know that the person or vehicle was at the location `8.166987 / 53.160455` during his/its trip `1866491` at `2021-07-05 10:35:01`**. In addition, you are able to calculate the **trip duration**.

You are also able to create a **line** by connecting all coordinates of a trip in sequence of the time stamp. And then, you can find out **at which location these trips do intersect with each other**.

From the line features, you can calculate their length (**trip's distance**). Together with the trip's duration, you are also able to calculate the average **walking or driving speed**.

(Your example data has no trips intersecting each other though. I am not sure what you mean with waiting time.)

---

Below an example script how to convert the points to lines and find the points where the trips cross each other's path:

```py
from itertools import combinations

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

from shapely.geometry import LineString

# Read CSV File
df = pd.read_csv("trips.csv")

# Create Points
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude),
    crs="EPSG:4326"
)
points = points.drop(columns=["latitude", "longitude"])

# Make sure Points are ordered (important)
points = points.sort_values(["tripId", "timestamp"])

# Create Lines
tolist = lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())
lines = points.groupby(["tripId"], as_index=False)["geometry"].apply(tolist)
lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame(lines, geometry="geometry", crs="EPSG:4326")
```

---

Find points where trips are crossing paths with each other:

```py
# Get Intersection Points
template={"tripA":[], "tripB":[], "geometry":[]}
intersection_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(template, geometry="geometry")
for index in combinations(lines.index, 2):
    
    combination = lines.loc[index,:]
    
    geometries = combination["geometry"].tolist()
    point = geometries[0].intersection(geometries[1])

    if point:  # LINESTRING EMPTY evaluates to false

        trips = combination["tripId"].tolist()
        row = pd.Series([trips[0], trips[1], point], index=intersection_points.columns)
        intersection_points = intersection_points.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

---

Write `intersection_points` to a CSV file:

```py
intersection_points["longitude"] = intersection_points.geometry.x
intersection_points["latitude"] = intersection_points.geometry.y

columns = ["tripA", "tripB", "latitude", "longitude"]
intersection_points.to_csv("intersections.csv", columns=columns)
```

---

Write created lines and the intersection points to shape files:

```py
# Write Shape Files
lines.to_file("trips.shp")
intersection_points.to_file("intersections.shp")
```

---

Example data with two trips intersecting each other (based on the question's example data):

```
"timestamp","tripId","longitude","latitude"
"2021-07-05 10:35:04","1866491","8.167035","53.160473"
"2021-07-05 10:35:03","1866491","8.167023","53.160469"
"2021-07-05 10:35:02","1866491","8.167007","53.160459"
"2021-07-05 10:35:01","1866491","8.166987","53.160455"
"2021-07-05 10:35:00","1866491","8.166956","53.160448"
"2021-07-05 10:34:20","1866491","8.167286","53.15919"
"2021-07-05 10:34:19","1866491","8.167328","53.15918"
"2021-07-05 10:34:18","1866491","8.16735","53.159165"
"2021-07-05 10:34:17","1866491","8.167371","53.159148"
"2021-07-05 10:34:16","1866491","8.167388","53.159124"
"2021-07-05 10:34:15","1866491","8.167399","53.159105"
"2021-06-30 20:25:30","1862861","8.211288","53.150848"
"2021-06-30 20:25:29","1862861","8.211264","53.150851"
"2021-06-30 20:25:28","1862861","8.211269","53.150842"
"2021-06-30 20:25:27","1862861","8.211273","53.150836"
"2021-06-30 20:25:26","1862861","8.211279","53.150836"
"2021-06-30 20:25:25","1862861","8.211259","53.150848"
"2021-06-30 20:25:24","1862861","8.211263","53.15085"
"2021-06-30 20:25:21","1862861","8.211455","53.150782"
"2021-06-30 20:25:19","1862861","8.211449","53.150792"
"2021-06-30 20:25:20","1862861","8.211453","53.150786"
"2021-06-30 20:25:18","1862861","8.166607","53.159654"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir for your answer, that was helpfull :D 
I just have another question, Is there a possibilty to calculate the Waiting time on every Intersection for each tripId ? 
Through your code, we have now also all the intersections 
should we probably only compare if the longitude and latitude changed or not? if it doesn't change that's mean that the user is waiting and then we should check if it's an intersection, if it's the case then we should see on the "timestamp" for how much time that taked.. or there is another way to calculate the waiting time on intersections

Comment: You are welcome. No, I don't see a way to extract a waiting time at the intersection. You would need to know when they arrived at the intersection and when they have departed. You don't have this information. At least not with the example data provided. Sorry.